# How can conditional rendering for array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have condition for profile page
I want to show user profile data
name . age etc..So I map array to get each user data
but problem is when there is no data in firestore , this profile page is empty
this is really disappointed
I want to conditional rendering the following rendering
But error is

```
jsx expression must have one parent element
```

so how can render this correctly

```
      
    return (

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    
     {values.map((value)=>(

                  
<React.Fragment key={value.id}>
<View style={styles.header}></View>
<Image style={styles.avatar} source={{uri : value.photo}}/>
 <View style={styles.body}>
   <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
  
    <Text style={styles.name}>{value.displayName}</Text>
       
        <View style={styles.label}>
              <Text >My Job is - </Text>
                    <Text>{value.job}</Text>
        </View>
                   
              <View style={styles.label}>
              <Text>My Age is - </Text>
                    <Text >{value.age}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.label}>
                 <Text>My Gender is  - </Text>
                    <Text >{value.gender}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.label}>
                 <Text>I want to meet  - </Text>
                    <Text >{value.interestIn}</Text>
                   </View>
   </View>
  
 </View>

</React.Fragment>

     ))}

    

      <View style={tw("p-10 flex-row items-center justify-between px-5")}>
       <Pressable 
              
              style={
               tw('p-3 rounded-xl bg-red-400')} onPress={goedit}>
             <Text style={styles.text}>Edit Profile</Text>
             </Pressable>

             <Pressable 
              
              style={
               tw('p-3 rounded bg-red-400')} onPress={logout}>
             <Text style={styles.text}>LOGOUT</Text>
             </Pressable>
       </View>
        
  </SafeAreaView>

      
    )
```

I want to show user profile page as template even no data in firestore
can someone help me

Comment: It's not clear what the context of the included code is, but you *may* need to wrap the whole thing in `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: still not get answet correctly , plz check my code and correct for conditional rendering

Comment: this value are from firestore ,I want to show is when data has ,profile data with firestore data will show ,if there no data in firestore, will only show this profile template without values

Answer (score 0):

Just add a <> ontop of the map and then </> on the bottom to close it.  If you need flex then you can switch out the <></> for

Comment: can you show me with my code in question.

Comment: well you edited it to add the safeareaview so you don't need to anymore, is the problem still there?

Comment: I still not success for conditional rendering .can you edit my code?

Comment: can you edit your question to say what values is equal to and what you expect to show on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, but paste your logic inside if statement:

```
const renderValues = () => {
    values.map((value) => {
      if (value) {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>data</Text>
          </View>
        );
      } else {
        return <View>no data</View>;
      }
    });
  };

  return <>{renderValues()}</>;
```

Comment: can you show with my code in question ,when I try your way. I get error .But I think this is reasonable way

Answer (score 0):

```
  const renderValues = () => {
    values.map((value) => {
      if (value) {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={value.id}>
            <View style={styles.header} />
            <Image style={styles.avatar} source={{ uri: value.photo }} />
            <View style={styles.body}>
              <View style={styles.bodyContent}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{value.displayName}</Text>

                <View style={styles.label}>
                  <Text>My Job is - </Text>
                  <Text>{value.job}</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.label}>
                  <Text>My Age is - </Text>
                  <Text>{value.age}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.label}>
                  <Text>My Gender is - </Text>
                  <Text>{value.gender}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.label}>
                  <Text>I want to meet - </Text>
                  <Text>{value.interestIn}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      } else {
        return <View>no data</View>;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <>
        {renderValues()}

        <View style={tw('p-10 flex-row items-center justify-between px-5')}>
          <Pressable style={tw('p-3 rounded-xl bg-red-400')} onPress={goedit}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Edit Profile</Text>
          </Pressable>

          <Pressable style={tw('p-3 rounded bg-red-400')} onPress={logout}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>LOGOUT</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Comment: only show two button and all profile frame are empty when I try this code.not work